# Error in ./~/@remix-run/router/dist/router.cjs.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Error in ./~/@remix-run/router/dist/router.cjs.js
Module parse failed: /home/sharib/Desktop/Full Stack Developer Tutorial/MERN Stack/loginForm/loginform/node_modules/@remix-run/router/dist/router.cjs.js Unexpected token (1073:8)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1073:8)
@ ./~/react-router-dom/dist/umd/react-router-dom.development.js 12:125-153

nodejs version : 16.17.0

npm version : 8.19.2

react-router version : 6.4.1

My App.js :-

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Navbar from "./Components/Navbar";
import Home from "./Components/Home";
import SignUp from "./Components/SignUp";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";

const App =()=> {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Navbar />}>
            <Route index element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="SignUp" element={< SignUp />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
};
export default App;
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

for me the issue was in react-scripts
dunno why but it was 0.9.5 so i changed it to 5 .0 .1 then run npm i react-scripts and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Running `npm audit fix --force` resolved this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I fixes the same issue by using the previous version of react-route-dom package. So, instead of using `react-router-dom@6.4.1`, simply get the older version:

> `npm install react-router-dom@6.0.1`

Make sure that `package.json` took over **that** version after installation.

Comment: react-router-dom@6.4.1 is causing the issue: Cannot find module "@remix-run/router". Can someone explain this bit further...?

Answer (score 0):

This fixes your problem.
The version you are using is not appropriate for this purpose. Change the version of the `"react-router-dom": "^6.15.1"`

to: `"react-router-dom": "^6.0.1"`

```
npm install react-router-dom@6.0.1
```